# How to execute 2 commands inside a single runas?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, cmd.exe, runas

1. When executed independently, they execute perfectly.
2. When executed in 2 consecutive `runas` statements, `chrome.exe` is executed before `robocopy` has had a chance to finish.
3. When placed inside a single `runas` separated by a `&`, it will not execute properly. Why?

```
 runas /savecred /user:chrome "robocopy C:\Users\chrome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome-Backup C:\Users\chrome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome /mir & \"!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\""
```

Comment: What is `!ProgramFiles(x86)!`? Should that be %ProgramFiles(x86)%? Or is this part of a batch file using delayed expansion?

Comment: What do you mean "it will not execute properly".  What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `runas` will only take one command.

You can, however, work around this by making a batch file of your multiple commands, and then using `runas` to execute your batch file.  Like this:

```
REM This file is CopyChromeStuffAndRunIt.bat

robocopy "C:\Users\chrome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome-Backup" "C:\Users\chrome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome" /mir
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\"
```

Then run your command:

```
runas /savecred /user:chrome "c:\batFileLocation\CopyChromeStuffAndRunIt.bat"
```

Alternatively, instead of running your command from the command line, you could put the `runas` command in another, separate batch file, so that you end up with two batch files.

Answer (score 0):

Your first idea to use the `&` to stick two commands together is the right way.

Use this sticked command and put it on a cmd like follows:

```
Runas /savecred /user:chrome "cmd /c ""robocopy C:\Users\chrome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome-Backup C:\Users\chrome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome /mir & \"!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\"""
```

This allows you to execute more than one command in one runas statement without using batch files.